# How to download only dist folder through npm

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, npm-install

- I use package.json to download project dependencies and then copy these files from node_modules directory to my project directory.

> > Command : D:\projectdirectory> npm install

- This downloads all the files/folders including src, dist, external, examples and so on. (specifically in jQuery and Bootstrap )
- However, I need only dist folder in production.

Is there any way to download only dist folder through npm?

Currently, as a work around, I am excluding unwanted directories through script while copying files from node_modules directory to my project directory.

- **package.json**

  ```
    {
  "name": "productionbuild",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Production Build",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "addJsDependency": "gulp",
    "addJsDependencyDev": "gulp devbuild",
    "updateWebdriver": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "startWebdriver": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "e2e": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor ./src/e2eTest/config.js",
    "e2eShowBrowser": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor ./src/e2eTest/config-head.js",
    "orchestrateE2e": "node ./src/e2eTest/e2e-runner.js",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/jest --coverage"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "fs-extra": "9.0.1",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-cli": "2.3.0",
    "mysql": "2.18.1",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "uglify-js": "3.13.8",
    "uglifycss": "0.0.29"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.5.2",
    "jqGrid": "5.5.5",
    "jquery": "3.6.0",
    "jquery-migrate": "3.3.1",
    "jquery-ui-built-themes": "1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "1.12.1"
  }
  ```

  }
- **gulpfile.js**

const fs = require('fs-extra');

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const {series} = require('gulp');
const option = {
    compress: false,
    mangle: false,
    ie8: true,
    output: {
        keep_quoted_props: true,
        quote_keys: false,
        quote_style: 3,
    },
}

function copyDependency(cb) {
    fs.remove('./src/main/webapp/jsp/resources', err => {
        if (err) return console.error(err)
        
        for (let dependency in fs.readJsonSync('./package.json').dependencies) {
            if (dependency) {
                if (fs.existsSync('./node_modules/' + dependency+'/dist')) {
                    fs.copy('./node_modules/' + dependency + '/dist', './src/main/webapp/jsp/resources/scriptlib/' + dependency + '/dist', err => {
                        if (err) return console.error(err)
                    })
                } else {
                    fs.copy('./node_modules/' + dependency, './src/main/webapp/jsp/resources/scriptlib/' + dependency, err => {
                        if (err) return console.error(err)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    });
    cb();
}
exports.default = series(copyDependency); // Prod
exports.devbuild = copyDependency; // Dev
```

Comment: `npm run build` usually does this for you, depending how your project is set up. Do you have webpack, gulp or similar package? Share your `package.json`. You should not need to copy `dist` directories manually when its set up correctly.

Comment: Hi NetUser :) Can you include any `npm` commands that you've already tried? Please add this by editing your questions as it's easy to miss this kind of things in comments and harder to read too.

Comment: Hi @PeterKrebs I just added package.json file. Yes I am using gulp. When I run npm install, it downloads all the dependencies mentioned in the package.json. 
The problem is, packages like jquery, bootstrap includes directories like 'src', 'examples' etc. which I dont want to be part of my production distribution. I need only 'dist' directory.

Comment: hi @tjheslin1, I am using 'npm install' command.

Comment: I would assume [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) will compile the modules you import and do the copying for you. Do you have a gulpfile to show here as well? You can add more instructions to the gulpfile. node module are usually handled by it as well.